# Make JPA entity field immutable in REST environment

Tags: java, rest, jpa, jersey, bean-validation

There are two simple JPA entities for Jersey REST web-service. Basically business item has a creator which refers to a user. When serializing it is not necessarily to show the creator of the business item to the client, so JsonIgnore annotation is there. Assume that I allow every user to update BusinessItem name via HTTP PUT request, but not to update creator value.

```
@Entity
public class BusinessItem {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "creator_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    User creator;
} 

@Entity
public class User {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, mappedBy = "creator")
    List<PhotoSpot> createdPhotoSpots;
}
```

The problem is that once PUT request with JSON body is received from a client and deserialized then creator field would be null. Then in order to update entity in a database I would need to retrieve a creator value from the DB by the business item id, substitute in the deserialized entity and only then apply update to the database. This all sounds like not elegant and boiler plate.

What would be an elegant solution for this type of problem?

Comment: Try to add @JoinColumn(name = "creator_id") Long creatorId referencing the same column. Then you can directly uppdate DB

Answer (score 2):

The direct association between a service and an entity can be a pragmatic design in very simple applications. However in many case this is not a suitable option. Managing properly entity relationships can be a good reason to have a more structured design.

In the usual design of standard MVC applications, it is a good practice *not* to use the entity directly as a [*JavaBean*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) accessed via the *View* / page (the entity is an [***Enterprise*** JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans) in an EJB container, not to be confused) . The implementation of a [*TransferObject* pattern](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/transferobject-139757.html) is an usual solution (beware, the sequence documented in that link is for a data retrieval operation, not an update). The controller commonly assumes the construction of the *TransferObject*. It then becomes a [recommended candidate for a DAO operation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html).

A REST service is not very different from an MVC pattern: in fact this is an [*Entity-Control-Boundary* pattern](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/patterns/enterprise/ecb/ecb.htm) (in the case of *Jersey* <= 2 applications, the distinction can be quite subtle, even if [this should evolve in *Java* EE 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mvc-2280472.html)). The service itself is a *Boundary* replacing the *View*.

In other words, according to *Core J2EE Patterns*, the elegant solution would be to feed a *TransferObject* with your PUT parameters: this object is then transmitted to the DAO. Then the DAO layer just has to retrieve a properly managed entity from the database to get the entities relationships and report the transferred values to update into the managed entity while preserving the relationships (this can be done with a DAO).

*Java* EE design can be quite challenging. The platform provides out of the box components very similar to pattern shapes. But in several cases these are not replacements. For example an *EntityManager* looks like a DAO. But using an explicit DAO usually provides a clear and understandable code while using directly the *EntityManager* can be quite verbose as transactions are not encapsulated.

**Conclusion**

In your situation, what seems important to me is the use of a DAO to encapsulate your database operations (this is only if you really need to map the relationships, otherwise a *@Transient* annotation would be a solution). You will anyway have to retrieve a managed entity before performing the *merge(...)* operation. The use of the *TransferObject* is not mandatory, this is just an advice to have a proper design. In many case this can lead to verbose code. You have several solutions to limit this: a simple [*Map*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) can limit the code, a utility such as [*BeanUtils*](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) can also be precious.

But avoiding a basic transfer operation in setting up a DAO can be challenging. In your case this would induce the use of a *MultivaluedMap* in the DAO layer,  which does not seem a very good idea on a dependency point of view as it links the *Model*/*Entity* and the *View*/*Boundary* components. This is probably why *Core J2EE patterns* introduces the *TransferObject*.

Comment: a JPA entity is **not** an Enterprise Java Bean

Comment: Thanks for the note, I fixed the text: what I meant was that it is not really suitable as a *JavaBean*